# Need to know whats happening in this code exactly

Tags: php, assignment-operator

I am little confused with this code

```
$name = $formData["name"] = stripslashes($mechanic_buy_name);
```

I found these code being used in one of the script downloaded from internet.
I need to know what is it all about?

Also will $name and $formData'["name"] will be having same value and that too with stripslashes.

For example if the value of $mechanic_buy_name = "SomeValue'WithQuote's";

What will be assigned to $name and $formData'["name"] in this case?

Curious to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$name = $formData["name"] = stripslashes($mechanic_buy_name);
```

is same as

```
$formData['name'] = stripslashes($mechanic_buy_name);
$name = $formData['name'];
```

explanation:

`$name` is equal to the value of `$formData['name']` where value of `$formData['name']` is equal to the value of `$mechanic_buy_name`

so in your example if:

```
$mechanic_buy_name = "SomeValue'WithQuote's";
$name = $formData["name"] = stripslashes($mechanic_buy_name);

echo $name . "\n" . $formData["name"];
```

will print the following:

```
SomeValue'WithQuote's
SomeValue'WithQuote's
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting two variables to the same value:

```
$name = $formData["name"] = stripslashes($mechanic_buy_name);
```

is the same thing as:

```
$name = stripslashes($mechanic_buy_name);
$formData["name"] = stripslashes($mechanic_buy_name);
```

The difference is that it works itself backwards:

`stripslashes($mechanic_buy_name)` is set to `$formData["name"]` and `$formData["name"]` is set to `$name`.

They are two independent variables. If you change one, it will not effect the other.

Comment: if you change $mechanic_buy_name it will affect both variables by the way